# Singular function with arc length 2

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ continuous and non-decreasing with the arc length 2?

The example I got is the Cantor's function. But, is there a way I can solve this problem without constructing the function? By 'without constructing the function' I mean a way to show only the existence.

Comment: Why are you so concerned about avoiding the construction of the function when its construction is so simple?

  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function#Definition

Comment: Hoping my question is not too naive... How do you define the arc length of your function ? The only formula I would have would be $\mathcal{L} = \int_{0}^{1} dx \, \sqrt{1 + (f'(x))^{2}}$, but it requires $f$ to be $\mathcal{C}^{1}$.

Comment: @RoryDaulton  ,because it was a question in an exam in which I would not have knowledge of the Cantor function. Is there a way to solve it (show that the function exists) without knowing that the Cantor function exists?

Comment: @jibe , arc length as defined here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Lengths_of_curves

But there is a way to prove that functions satisfying these properties are differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: there are many continuous monotone and rectifiable functions with arc length 2.

Comment: @zairhenrique Thanks for the link. The difficulty seems to be that an arc length of $2$ is the maximum arc length for any such function $f$ (Is it correct ?) As a consequence, the following usual scheme does not work. Imagine we could define a family of functions $f_{\epsilon}$, for $\epsilon \in [0,1]$, such that $\mathcal{L} (f_{\epsilon})$ is a smooth function of $\epsilon$, and $\mathcal{L} (f_{0}) = \ell_{0} < 2$ and $\mathcal{L} (f_{1}) = \ell_{1} > 2$. Then by continuity, we could prove the existence of $f_{\epsilon_0}$ of length 2 without exhibiting it. That's all I can say...

Comment: Yes, 2 is the maximum arc length...

Comment: This became a question of "what knowledge are you expected to have on an exam", which is difficult to answer for those who know nothing about the exam. Do you know measure theory? If a measure $\mu$ is mutually singular to the Lebesgue measure and has no atoms, then something  like $f(x) = \mu([x,1])$ works.

Comment: Assume only a good knowledge of one variable calculus and introductory real analysis.